# GET/POST запросы с максимально простым кодом

Tags: java, https, jar, requests

Мне нужно написать обобщённые методы: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

Принимают они на вход url и параметры, возвращают строку (json).

Всё на что я натыкался в интернете было с усложненным кодом, в добавок оперирующим байтами. 
Хотелось узнать, нет ли какой библиотеки, которая бы позволила упростить код?

Всё что я делаю в этих методах это:

- добавляю заголовки
- отправляю GET/DELETE запрос url (параметры уже включены в url)
- отправляю POST/PUT запрос с url и параметрами в виде пар ключ-значение.
- принимаю json-строку и парсю её.

На C# я использовал HttpClient, который был максимально прост в использовании. Вот пример реализации на C# (код мой): https://github.com/MrModest/ShikiApiLib/blob/master/ShikiApiLib/ApiQuery.cs

Хотелось бы сделать аналог кода выше на Java.

P.S. **Я не прошу написать код за меня.** Я прошу посоветовать мне библиотеки, которые позволят не писать кучу лишней мишуры, которая вполне могла иметь значение по умолчанию и не требовать от меня дополнительных строк кода.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66055/discussion-on-question-by-mr-modest-get-post-----).

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много. Можно использовать например Apache HttpClient для клиента и что-нибудь типа JSON.simple, Gson, Jackson, Fastjson для парсинга JSON.

Comment: Касается первого: пока гуглил, наткнулся на много упоминаний того, что он устарел и не рекомендуется к использованию. Или я что-то путаю? Касательно второго: не заметил в примерах десериализацию в класс. Он это вообще умеет? =/ А вообще я думал GSON использовать, только вот там инструкция для Maven, не понял где jar достать, а с Maven я работать не умею, у меня обычный голый консольный проект без фреймворков..

Comment: @AndreyDolgikh, постарайтесь более развёрнутые ответы давать. Предложили Apache HTTPClient - приведите пример запроса на нём.

Comment: @Mr.Modest, использовать GSON - хорошая идея. Скачать GSON можно всё из того же maven репозитория- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Comment: @МихаилРебров ого, круто, спасибо) осталось только с сабжем разобраться)

Comment: @Mr.Modest, научиться пользоваться Maven несложно. Он вам в будущем очень сильно поможет и в загрузках не будет помойки из jar'ников

Comment: @МихаилРебров это просто подключаемый менеджер пакетов (аля NuGet в VisualStudio)? Или там ещё какие-то нюансы есть?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Думаете ссылки на туториал с примерами в наше время уже не достаточно? :)

Comment: @Mr.Modest,  в первом приближении -да, хотя там есть и куча дополнительных плюшек.

Comment: @AndreyDolgikh, если бы все могли гуглить и читать туториалы на английском, то этого сайта бы не было.У данного ресурса есть определенные правила и пункт по поводу ответов-ссылок также имеется.

Comment: @AndreyDolgikh это негласное правило на SO для того, чтобы если со временем ссылка станет не валидной, человек, который придёт с Гугла сможет хоть какую-то полезную информацию для себя почерпнуть, помимо нерабочих ссылок)

Comment: @Mr.Modest данный вопрос не имеет "правильного" ответа, кроме того, что вариантов множество и надо идти читать документацию и подбирать подходящий. Куски кода ничего никому не скажут.

Comment: @AndreyDolgikh ну, возможно в данном случае так и есть. Я просто предположил возможную логику мыслей Михаила)